# How to do Basic Authentication from React Axios GET call to a SpringBoot microservice

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, microservices

[Postman Request Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCPi5.jpg)
[image]
I am using axios.get() to call a secured SpringBoot Microservice but it returns a 401 Unauthorized response.
Postman returns the output as expected for SpringBoot Microservice but not the React App

I have tried all the possibilities available on internet but in vain.

Please help me get a solution to this.

React Call: passing auth as parameter as it is the way to do Basic Authentication in Axios

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/hellouser/greet/',
     {},
    {auth:{
        username:'demouser',
        password:'demopassword'
        }}).then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach instead

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/hellouser/greet/', {
    params: {},
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: {
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword'
    }
})
```

You might also check the version of the library. It may vary from one to another

Comment: if I use your way it gives me a CORS error like:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/hellouser/greet/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Since you are calling the server from a different host, you shall use the CORS flag. Otherwise you won't be able to make the call. And your server also need to add the `Allow Control Allow Origin` Header. See https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/569

Comment: I put your auth parameter in header and it seems to work partially. When I hit my API in browser through I get a popup asking for username and password. I dont want that as I am already passing the credentials through auth.